# Facebook App calling after QR - Code Scanning

Tags: facebook, qr-code

I am facing an issue when calling my Facebook App after scanning QR - Code.

Problem: When I scan my QR - Code its open correct Facebook App URL but asking for login twice one is normal Desktop browser view & second time in Facebook Mobile view & when I insert login details second time it navigate me on Facebook Mobile version home page not on my app page.

Answer (score 0):

Please have look below url,it will help you
Url:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

My problem is access Facebook app page in mobile browser not login with Facebook.